# How to run hector_ugv in gazebo?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI,
I am interested in the dual ackermann steering model similar to that of the hector_ugv. Before attempting to write a model from scratch, I would like to check if there is any existing package that I can use to run in gazebo. I did find some information here: https://code.google.com/p/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/source/browse/branches/fuerte/hector_ugv_common/hector_ugv_gazebo/urdf/hector_ugv.gazebo.xacro?r=389

I was able to spawn the robot, but have no clue on how to control it. The all wheel drive plugin in particular is missing.
The Ackermann group does focus on single ackermann steering. Unfortunately I need to navigate a long robot in tight spaces, hence a dual steering is inevitable.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/162571/how-to-run-hector_ugv-in-gazebo?/) by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 528 on 2014-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We currently have not published the latest version of the vehicle and I´m unfortunately very time constrained, so won´t be able to provide it within a short time frame. I´ll look into adding the all wheel steering plugin to [hector_gazebo_plugins](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_gazebo_plugins) though. This should allow using the hector_ugv model you found.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on 2014-05-07**:
I am currently trying to use one of the simple models posted by Austin in the Ackermann group. This should be sufficient for now. But do add more info on the hector_ugv when you find time. The robot is one of a kind ! :)